# Next.js with a Express server how to call custom error page?

Tags: reactjs, express, error-handling, next.js

I have an express middleware in my Next.js app that could pass to the express instance an error:

```
function (req, res, expressNext) {
   //Returns an error:  
   expressNext(err)
}
```

I don't understand how to render the Error custom page from my Express Error handler function.

I reproduce a problem example [here](https://github.com/ale-grosselle/express-next-js) where:

- my base path is set to "/preferences" ([next.config.js](https://github.com/ale-grosselle/express-next-js/blob/master/next.config.js))
- attach to "/preferences" a middleware that returns an error ([see](https://github.com/ale-grosselle/express-next-js/blob/master/server.js#L12))
- And my error handler:

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log("ERROR HANDLER WITH ERROR", err);
  res.status(err);
  return app.render(req, res, '/_error', req.query);
}
```

But instead of rendering `_next.js` component it returns all assets with status code 500:
[image: Schermata 2020-11-21 alle 16 24 34]

It access properly to the error handler; what am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Middleware:

```
server.use('/favorites', async (req, res, nextFunction) => {
    //Log and Handle error only for the HTML page
    if (req.path === '/') {
       nextFunction(500)
    } else {
      nextFunction();
    }
  });
```

Error handler:

```
async function errorHandler(err, req, res, next): Promise<void> {
  res.status(500);
  const error = await app.renderToHTML(req, res, '/_error');
  res.send(error);
}
```